# Sql bigger than average 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have a problem finding the solution to this.

This is the question: give the name of the os with the highest average intervention units (`eenheden int` in `interventie`). The average is the total of intervention units divided by the total of servers with that os.

This is what the database looks like:

[image]

This is what I came up with, I have no idea if this will work

```
SELECT 
    os 
FROM 
    servers s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         serial, 
         COUNT(serial) AS aantalinterventies 
     FROM   
         interventies) AS interventies USING (serial) 
GROUP BY        
    os 
HAVING
    aantalinterventies/Count(s.serial) >= ALL (SELECT aantalinterventies2 / COUNT(se.serial) 
                                               FROM servers s 
                                               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                   (SELECT 
                                                        serial, 
                                                        COUNT(serial) AS aantalinterventies2
                                                    FROM interventies) AS interventies USING (serial)) AS interventiesrest
```

this is the answer i found: thanks to simonare!

```
selet os from (select os, sum(eenheden) / count( distinct serial) avg_unit
  from server s
  inner join intervantie i on i.FK = s.PK
  group by os
  order by avg_unit desc
) as T
where avg_unit = (select max(avg_unit) from (select os, sum(eenheden) / count( distinct serial) avg_unit
  from server s
  inner join intervantie i on i.FK = s.PK
  group by os
  order by avg_unit desc
) as T)
```

Comment: what did you try so far? It is even very hard to understand what you really need

Comment: well i know how to count the number of servers, and the total of intervention units per os. the problem i am having is combining them all in one query. this is a question from an exam. you don't get to try it on the actual database, it is all on paper.

Comment: write your draft here, so that we will see what you have tried so far.

Comment: i added  the sql code i have

Comment: why do you need to use installattie table and serial column?

Comment: we need to answer in standard sql code, serial is the primary key and the installatie table is not needed for this exercise

Comment: In general showing table definitions as `create table` statements ([formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) is preferred over [screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generic SQL, If you tag your RDBMS system, you can have more specific answer

```
with T as 
(
  select os, avg(eenheden) avg_unit
  from server s
  inner join intervantie i on i.FK = s.PK
  group by os
  order by avg_unit desc
)
selet os from T 
where avg_unit = (select max(avg_unit) from T)
```

---

```
with T as 
(
  select os, sum(eenheden) / count( distinct serial) avg_unit
  from server s
  inner join intervantie i on i.FK = s.PK
  group by os
  order by avg_unit desc
)
selet os from T 
where avg_unit = (select max(avg_unit) from T)
```

Comment: the average that needs to be calculated is the sum of the "eenheden" divided by the number of servers with that os name. out of this list i need the one with the biggest average. the server tabel can contain multiple servers with the same os name.

Comment: i don't think we can use the with T as (). We never learned this in the lessons but i hope i can try further with your code. if you know a solution that doesn't use this i would be very gratefull. But thanks already :)